# Why is modulation index called modulation index?

Tags: frequency-modulation, fsk

The phase of CPFSK is defined as in [this, page 4](https://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/ee/muqaibel/Courses/EE571%20Digital%20Communications%20I/notes/Digital%20Modulation%20Schemes/Continuous-Phase%20Frequency-Shift%20Keying%20(CPFSK).pdf)

$$\phi(t;I) = \theta_n + 2 \pi h I_n q(t-nT)$$

for $nT \leq t \leq (n+1)T$, with $h$ defined $h=2 f_d T$ called modulation index.

What does it mean by "modulation index" that being the product of peak frequency deviation $f_d$ and symbol duration $T$? I mean "index" of what?

What is the reason that for $h=0.5$ then $f_d=\frac{1}{4T}$ we get MSK the smallest frequency seperation assuring orthogonality? Isn't it $\frac{1}{2T}$?

Is the meaning of "modulation index" the same in CPM $\phi(t;I) = 2\pi\sum_{k\leq n} I_k h_k q(t-kT)$?

Comment: "Modulation index" is an overloaded term, borrowed from FM. Its precise meaning varies from one textbook to the next and from one modulation type to another. In general, it provides an indication of how much the frequency/phase/angle changes as the baseband (message) signal changes.

Comment: yeah, don't get hung up on words too much. They're just words; even if consistent naming would have been desirable, it just didn't happen in this context :/ . Now, I think you have a second question hidden in there, but I don't quite understand it. What exactly, not using the *word* "modulation index", do you want to compare between CPFSK and CPM?

Comment: @MBaz thanks. But even in the FM context, why is it called "index"?

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks. Actually I want to see how the modulation index influences the waveform.  For example, for what purpose should I choose a small modulation index? About the comparison CPFSK vs CPM, I thought that CPFSK is simply a special case of CPM. Is there anything interesting should be pointed out?

Comment: @CathMaillon but that seems to be a very very different question than what you ask here in the question! (and you kind of failed at asking *without using the word modulation index* ;) ). Maybe you want to ask a new question that literally just asks: "We can define the general case of a CPFSK waveform as defined on page 4 as $\phi = …$; now, for which purposes would I choose $h$ to be high or low?"

Comment: @MarcusMüller I know. I will ask the question when I grasp a little more about this modulation.